# col-push-md-6 & col-pull-md-6 are overlapping in the middle

Tags: css, overlap

Pretty basic question, but I am having an issue with this:
[image]

It appears that the second row has a slight margin on both sides but I believe it may have something to do with the columns as opposed to the row. Any help is greatly appreciated.

HTLM for reference:

```
<div id="fws_5c424b55ca4df" data-midnight="dark" data-bg-mobile-hidden="" class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_row full-width-content vc_row-o-full-height vc_row-o-columns-stretch vc_row-o-equal-height vc_row-flex  vc_row-o-content-middle standard_section vertically-align-columns  " style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; left: 0px; margin-left: -90px; width: 1068px; visibility: visible; min-height: 1226px;"><div class="row-bg-wrap" data-bg-animation="none"><div class="inner-wrap "><div class="row-bg    " style=""></div></div><div class="row-bg-overlay"></div></div><div class="col span_12 dark left" style="min-height: 1226px;">
<div style="padding-top: 85.4375px; padding-bottom: 85.4375px;" class="vc_col-sm-6 vc_col-md-push-6 wpb_column column_container vc_column_container col padding-8-percent instance-12" data-using-bg="true" data-t-w-inherits="default" data-border-radius="none" data-shadow="none" data-border-animation="" data-border-animation-delay="" data-border-width="none" data-border-style="solid" data-border-color="" data-bg-cover="" data-padding-pos="all" data-has-bg-color="true" data-bg-color="#0f5a99" data-bg-opacity="1" data-hover-bg="" data-hover-bg-opacity="1" data-animation="" data-delay="0"><div class="column-bg-overlay" style="opacity: 1; background-color: #0f5a99;"></div>
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">

<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <h6 style="padding-bottom: 8px; color: #b1dbff;">METHODOLOGY</h6>
```

Text here....

```
    </div>
</div>

        </div> 
    </div>
</div> 

<div style="min-height: 798px;" class="vc_col-sm-6 mobile-column-bg vc_col-md-pull-6 wpb_column column_container vc_column_container col centered-text no-extra-padding instance-13 no-left-margin" data-using-bg="true" data-t-w-inherits="default" data-border-radius="none" data-shadow="none" data-border-animation="" data-border-animation-delay="" data-border-width="none" data-border-style="solid" data-border-color="" data-bg-cover="true" data-padding-pos="all" data-has-bg-color="false" data-bg-color="" data-bg-opacity="1" data-hover-bg="" data-hover-bg-opacity="1" data-animation="" data-delay="0"><div class="column-image-bg-wrap" data-bg-animation="none"><div class="inner-wrap"><div class="column-image-bg" style=" background-image: url('http://adverthealth.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/rowing-img.png'); "></div></div></div><div class="column-bg-overlay"></div>
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">

        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: My guess is that you have not added row wrapper around columns

Comment: Just updated it with the html. Its a Salient wordpress theme. I will try row wrapper now.